# Creating a Google Script App pop-up that is not document bound

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

There are a few solutions for creating pop-ups bound to Google documents but I haven't found a solution that I can just put in a **stand-alone** google script app without creating a google document nor separate HTML document for it. (Correction, I think there was an old way that is deprecated now `UiApp.createApplication()`)

I am thinking about creating a handful of apps that I'd like to use regularly without creating an HTML GUI interface. The Google script will be searching my google drive folder for items and organizing my drive so i wanted just a quick and simple (if even dirty) way of popping up a message if a folder doesn't exist.

```
myFunction() {
  alert("File does not exist");
}
```

`Logger.log()` is not equivalent but if someone knows of a way to have that popup automatically without the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> hotkey, then that would be good enough for now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throw a new <kbd>[ERROR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)</kbd>:

```
function myFunction() {
  throw new Error("File does not exist");
}
```

Comment: Yep that will work for now. Quick and dirty. Would be nice if it: (1) Popped up lower on the screen (2) Didn't look like an error dialog.   Wonder if there are other options like that.  Thanksssss !!!!

Comment: @PPL There is a new script editor in the works. It "may" be able to satisfy your needs later.

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster, I really appreciate that great news. It would be nice if I could run those scripts from the google drive directly with a double click too :-)